# Can't see the errors on classic asp sites

Tags: asp-classic, windows-server-2008

There are sites that I am trying to migrate from Windows 2003 Server to 2008. Some of the sites shows blank pages when I visit them.

Obviously there are errors but I can't see anything.

I already enabled client side errors and detailed error pages but no luck.

Any idea ?

Comment: Any chance you have `On Error Resume Next` in your code somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So just to make sure you did all of this:

1. In IIS under Debugging Properties you set: `Send Errors to Browser` to `True`.
2. In IIS under `Error Pages` you set the settings to `Detailed Errors`.
3. Give write permissions on the website folder to the IIS_ISRS builtin group
4. Checked all of the source code for something like: `On Error Resume Next`, `On Error GoTo` or `If Err.Number`.
5. If using Internet Explorer you have to disable `Show Friendly HTTP Error Messages` in located in `Tools/Internet Options/Advanced` Under the `Browsing` section uncheck/disable `Show Friendly HTTP Error Messages`.

Comment: It seems it doesn't work but I have an extra information. I just figured out, the problem related with MDB databases. Strangely, if the system couldn't connect to an MDB, I don't see any error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Classic pipeline? If so only thing left is to make sure in the source code that there is no code that says `on error resume next` also make sure that you have classic-asp installed on the server for example you can just create a new page name it something like test.asp and inside write some code like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test ASP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
strMessage = "Hello World"
Response.Write (strMessage)
%>
</body>
</html>
```

then in your web browser run it and see if you get a message saying Hello World if not then you will need to install classic-asp.

**Please Note:** Classic ASP in **NOT** installed by default on IIS 7.0 / 7.5 [look here if you need instructions on how to install it.](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/562/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis/)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the I am looking for. Classic ASP sites is working and I just need to see errors.

For example, following line causing an error but I can't see anything. 

"conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=D:\vhosts\somedomain.com\httpdocs\db\some.mdb;"

I know how can I fix the problem but it doesn't work some cases and couldn't figure out why? I already enabled necessary options to see errors but no luck.