# Classic ASP internal error on contact form

Tags: asp-classic

My form takes me to an internal error page upon submission. I have all the fields defined, and my SMTP info passing through. It looks as if everything should work. But it simply doesn't.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

```
<%
'Declaring Variables
Dim smtpserver,youremail,yourpassword,ContactUs_Name,ContactUs_Email
Dim ContactUs_Subject,ContactUs_Body,Action,IsError

' Edit these 3 values accordingly
smtpserver = "mysmtperserver"
youremail = "myemail"
yourpassword = "mypassword"

' Grabbing variables from the form post
ContactUs_Name = Server.HTMLEncode(Request("ContactUs_Name"))
ContactUs_Email = Server.HTMLEncode(Request("ContactUs_Email"))
ContactUs_Subject = Server.HTMLEncode(Request("ContactUs_Subject"))
ContactUs_Body = Server.HTMLEncode(Request("ContactUs_Body"))
ContactUs_Captcha = Request("recaptcha_response_field")
Action = Request("Action")

' Used to check that the email entered is in a valid format
Function IsValidEmail(Email)
    Dim ValidFlag,BadFlag,atCount,atLoop,SpecialFlag,UserName,DomainName,atChr,tAry1
    ValidFlag = False
        If (Email <> "") And (InStr(1, Email, "@") > 0) And (InStr(1, Email, ".") > 0) Then
            atCount = 0
            SpecialFlag = False
            For atLoop = 1 To Len(Email)
            atChr = Mid(Email, atLoop, 1)
                If atChr = "@" Then atCount = atCount + 1
                If (atChr >= Chr(32)) And (atChr <= Chr(44)) Then SpecialFlag = True
                If (atChr = Chr(47)) Or (atChr = Chr(96)) Or (atChr >= Chr(123)) Then SpecialFlag = True
                If (atChr >= Chr(58)) And (atChr <= Chr(63)) Then SpecialFlag = True
                If (atChr >= Chr(91)) And (atChr <= Chr(94)) Then SpecialFlag = True
            Next
            If (atCount = 1) And (SpecialFlag = False) Then
                BadFlag = False
                tAry1 = Split(Email, "@")
                UserName = tAry1(0)
                DomainName = tAry1(1)
            If (UserName = "") Or (DomainName = "") Then BadFlag = True
            If Mid(DomainName, 1, 1) = "." then BadFlag = True
            If Mid(DomainName, Len(DomainName), 1) = "." then BadFlag = True
                ValidFlag = True
            End If
        End If
        If BadFlag = True Then ValidFlag = False
        IsValidEmail = ValidFlag
End Function
%>

<%
If Action = "SendEmail" Then

    ' Here we quickly check/validate the information entered
    ' These checks could easily be improved to look for more things
    If IsValidEmail(ContactUs_Email) = "False" Then
        IsError = "Yes"
        Response.Write("<font color=""red"">Please enter valid Email address.</font><br>")
    End If

    If ContactUs_Name = "" Then
        IsError = "Yes"
        Response.Write("<font color=""red"">Please enter your Name.</font><br>")
    End If

    If ContactUs_Subject = "" Then
    IsError = "Yes"
        Response.Write("<font color=""red"">Please enter a Subject.</font><br>")
    End If

    If ContactUs_Body = "" Then
        IsError = "Yes"
        Response.Write("<font color=""red"">Please include Message.</font><br>")
    End If

    if ContactUs_Captcha = "" Then
        IsError = "Yes"
        Response.Write("<font color=""red"">Captcha Required.</font><br>")
    End If

End If

' If there were no input errors and the action of the form is "SendEMail" we send the email off
If Action = "SendEmail" And IsError <> "Yes" Then

    Dim strBody

    ' Here we create a nice looking html body for the email
    strBody = strBody & "<font face=""Arial"">Contact Us Form submitted at " & Now() &  vbCrLf & "<br><br>"
    strBody = strBody & "From http://" & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") &  vbCrLf & "<br>"
    strBody = strBody & "IP " & Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR") & vbCrLf & "<br>"
    strBody = strBody & "Name" & " : " & " " & Replace(ContactUs_Name,vbCr,"<br>") & "<br>"
    strBody = strBody & "Email" & " : " & " " & Replace(ContactUs_Email,vbCr,"<br>") & "<br>"
    strBody = strBody & "Subject" & " : " & " " & Replace(ContactUs_Subject,vbCr,"<br>") & "<br>"
    strBody = strBody & "<br>" & Replace(ContactUs_Body,vbCr,"<br>") & "<br>"
    strBody = strBody & "</font>"

    Dim ObjSendMail
    Set ObjSendMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 

    'This section provides the configuration information for the remote SMTP server.

    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network).
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = smtpserver
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False 'Use SSL for the connection (True or False)
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = youremail
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = yourpassword

    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

    'End remote SMTP server configuration section==

    ObjSendMail.To = youremail
    ObjSendMail.Subject = ContactUs_Subject
    ObjSendMail.From = ContactUs_Email

    ' we are sending a html email.. simply switch the comments around to send a text email instead
    ObjSendMail.HTMLBody = strBody
    'ObjSendMail.TextBody = strBody

    ObjSendMail.Send

    Set ObjSendMail = Nothing 

' change the success messages below to say or do whatever you like
' you could do a response.redirect or offer a hyperlink somewhere.. etc etc
%>
```

Comment: ..and the mystery error message is???

Comment: The internal error? Its your standard internal error 
"
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log."

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849428/cant-see-the-errors-on-classic-asp-sites

Comment: I am unable to turn on the debugger at this time thats why I am posting here to see if theres a alternative problem or suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, there are just too many things that can go wrong. You simply have to turn on detailed error messages, otherwise you might as well give up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't do much with custom error pages then you can use "On Error Resume Next" to trap errors, something like:

```
On Error Resume Next
    'Put your code in here



    'Write out error messages
    If err.number > 0 then
        response.write "Error: err.description & " on line number <strong>" & err.line & "</strong>"
    END IF
On Error Goto 0
```

Caveat: I'd just recommend taking this out once you've got your code working as can mask issues if not used carefully. Instead look at getting some proper error handling and logging in place using custom error pages.

Just at a quick glance... this section looks to be missing an END IF

```
        If (atCount = 1) And (SpecialFlag = False) Then
            BadFlag = False
            tAry1 = Split(Email, "@")
            UserName = tAry1(0)
            DomainName = tAry1(1)
```