# Can't see what's wrong with my Classic ASP code

Tags: html, asp-classic

I can't seem to find the bug in the code. It's meant to output the times table, of a variable taken from the user, from an HTML form. I get the 500 programming error.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Times Tables</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Times Table: </h1>
    <%
        isValid = True
        mult = request.form("multiple")
        if not IsNumeric(mult) then
            isValid = False
            response.write("Not a number. Please try again...")
        end if
        if mult > 12 And mult < 1 then
            isValid = False
            response.write("Out of range. Please try again...")
        end if
        if isValid
        %>
            <table style="width:75%">
            <%
            For i = 1 to 12
                %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= i %></td>
                    <td><%= mult %></td>
                    <th><%= (i * mult) %></th>
                </tr>
                <%
            Next
        end if
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In order to see the errors rather then a generic HTTP 500 follow [A: Can't see the errors on classic asp sites](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11866550/692942).

Comment: Thank you, I'll check that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `Then` after `If isValid`

It should be

```vb
If isValid Then
```

and a logical issue the

```vb
If mult > 12 And mult < 1 Then
```

will never evaluate to `True`, because the `mult`variable cannot be both greater than 12 and less than 1 (*at the same time*).

You should use the `Or` Operator instead.

```vb
If mult > 12 Or mult < 1 Then
```

Comment: Thanks, anything else? or should that work? I can't run it unfortunately, as the server is at school